# How to Get a Query Result even if Result is 0 or Null

Tags: sql, oracle, null

I am hoping to get an answer to this problem.

I am using SQL Developer to write queries, connected to an Oracle database. What I need is, if the query result is nothing (null or 0, I guess?), I still need something to show up. As of now, when the query result is nothing, then nothing but column headers come up.

The code below is what I have/tried so far with no success.

```
SELECT
to_char(rs.cr_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') "Date",
COUNT(os.ord_id) "RTS Returned Orders"

FROM return_sku rs,
order_sku os

WHERE
rs.s_method Like '%RTS%'
AND trunc(created_date) = trunc(SYSDATE)
AND os.ord_sku_id = rs.ord_sku_id

GROUP BY to_char(rs.cr_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) rts
```

This works fine when there is an "RTS" in the s_method column; as in, a number will appear in my query result. The problem is that when there are no query results where rs.s_method has "RTS" in it, my query just returns column headers and nothing else (see below).

```
Date      | RTS Returned Orders
------------------------------
```

I need it so that when there are no results with "RTS" in s_method, it will return a row with the date and the number 0 in the "RTS Returned Orders" column. Something like below:

```
Date      | RTS Returned Orders
------------------------------
12/4/2013 |         0
```

I have tried using decode and NVL to no avail. Either I am not using them correctly, or there is something else that I can use that I am unaware of.

Please help! Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best Regards,

-Anthony C.

Comment: Can you post an [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com) with the table structures and some sample data? Also, which table does the `created_date` column belong to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the query that you want uses conditional aggregation, instead of filtering in the `where` clause:

```
SELECT to_char(rs.cr_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') as "Date",
       sum(case when rs.s_method Like '%RTS%' then 1 else 0 end) as "RTS Returned Orders"
FROM return_sku rs join
     order_sku os
     on os.ord_sku_id = rs.ord_sku_id
WHERE trunc(created_date) = trunc(SYSDATE)
GROUP BY to_char(rs.cr_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Note a few things.  The `group by` is unnecessary, because you are only returning one row (but I'm leaving it in because it was part of your original question).  I also fixed the `join` syntax to use standard join syntax (`join` . . . `on`) rather than implicit joins.

Comment: I tried this code and it is not working. What I mean is, I know that there are 17 rows in this result that have "RTS" somewhere in the s_method column, but when I run the code above the "RTS Returned Orders" number given is 155.

The data entry for 12/4 in my system has it such that out of everything from that day (today), 17 of say 50 orders returned (entered data) have "RTS" written in the s_method field. I need that number to come up in my query result.

Rather, to add to that, on any given day that there are no RTS', I need this query result to say "0" instead of not returning anything.

Comment: To give a better idea of what I have been trying to do, see below. I really appreciate the help so far.


    `SELECT
    to_char(rs.created_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') "Date",
    decode(COUNT(rs.ship_method), 0, '0', COUNT(rs.ship_method))

    FROM return_sku rs,
    order_sku os

    WHERE 
    trunc(created_date) = trunc(SYSDATE)
    AND os.order_sku_id = rs.order_sku_id
    AND rs.ship_method Like '%RTS%'

    GROUP BY to_char(rs.created_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY');`

Comment: @aCarella . . . You are presumably getting too many rows because the `join` condition is only on the SKU and not on the order id.  You might want to ask another question to clarify what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
select "date", sum('MM/DD/YYYY') "Date") 
from 
(select to_char(sysdate, 'MM/DD/YYYY') "Date"
, 0 "'MM/DD/YYYY') "Date"
from dual
union

SELECT
to_char(rs.cr_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY') "Date",
COUNT(os.ord_id) "RTS Returned Orders"

FROM return_sku rs,
order_sku os

WHERE
rs.s_method Like '%RTS%'
AND trunc(created_date) = trunc(SYSDATE)
AND os.ord_sku_id = rs.ord_sku_id

GROUP BY to_char(rs.cr_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY')) rts
) temp
```

Not sure about the syntax with all those quoted aliases, but the general idea should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery.

This will be pseudo code.

Select check if columnA is null then show the alternate value
From
(Select columnA from your current query) as MyQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH os_counts AS (
    SELECT COUNT(rs.ord_id) AS "RTS Returned Orders",
           os.ord_id
    FROM   order_sku os
           LEFT OUTER JOIN
           ( SELECT ord_id
             FROM   return_sku
             WHERE  s_method LIKE '%RTS%'
           ) rs
           ON ( os.ord_sku_id = rs.ord_sku_id )
    AND    TRUNC(created_date) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
    GROUP BY
          os.ord_id
)
SELECT TO_CHAR( NVL( rs.cr_date, SYSDATE ), 'MM/DD/YYYY') "Date",
       "RTS Returned Orders"
FROM   os_counts os
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       return_sku rs
       ON ( os.ord_sku_id = rs.ord_sku_id );
```

I have no idea which table your `created_date` column is in so you might need to move that statement about.

The lower `LEFT OUTER JOIN` might be able to be an `INNER JOIN` but I have no idea on your table structures and dependencies.